# Why is "Susan picked the baby up gently so as not to wake him" correct?

Tags: word-choice

Why is the first sentence correct whereas the second one is not?

> Susan picked the baby up gently so as not to wake him.

vs

> Susan picked the baby up gently so to do not wake him.

Comment: Where did you get "to do not" from?

Answer (score 1):

"So as to"/"in order to" introduce clauses of purpose which explain the goal behind an action. So, Susan picked up the baby gently and her goal was not to wake him.

The structure "so to do not + verb" is not correct. Thank you.